# Apply format painter on multiple slides in Power Point

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

`Format Painter` is a very useful tool in `MS Office` applications since you could copy the format of a text for example to another text or group of text. However, what if I want to apply a format in `Power Point` to multiple slides say 10 out of 20 slides, is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. Just double click at "Format Painter" button and then you will be able to choose multiple slides but not just one of them. Press Esc or "Format Painter" button again when you are ready.

Comment: Double click works but you have to click individually on the text that you want to format and to every slides. What I want is I use `Format Painter` and click the beginning slide (say slide 5) and then click the last slide that I want to format with (say slide 15) and voila all those slides are formatted. Thanks for your answer by the way.

Comment: Try to click at slide #5 hold Shift Key and click at slide #15.

Comment: I see what you mean. You would like to pick "Format Painter" and use it at multiple slides at once so every Object has the same style at all slides at once? Well, I'm not sure it's possible cause every Object is unique so the program don't know which objects do you actually want to affect. So you have double click at "Format Painter" tool and manually check objects at every slide you want to affect.